# Gas estimation error

Tags: solidity, remix, gas, ganache

I have created a contract on remix.ethereum.org and started the Ganache(http://truffleframework.com/ganache/) as private blockchain.
On the Remix I have configured Remix to work with Ganache through custom web3 provider which is my localhost.

It's a simple voting Dapp:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;


contract VotingDapp {

  mapping (bytes32 => uint8) public votesReceived;

  bytes32[] public candidateList;

  function VotingDapp(bytes32[] candidateNames) public {
    // constructor
    candidateList = candidateNames;
  }

  function totalVotesFor(bytes32 candidate) public view returns (uint8) {
    if(validCandidate(candidate) == false) revert();
    return votesReceived[candidate];
  }

  function voteForCandidate(bytes32 candidate) public {
    if(validCandidate(candidate) == false) revert();
    votesReceived[candidate] += 1;
  }

  function validCandidate(bytes32 candidate) public view returns (bool) {
    for(uint i = 0; i < candidateList.length; i++){
      if(candidateList[i] == candidate){
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  function totalVotesReceived() external view returns(uint){
      uint sum = 0;
      for(uint i = 0; i < candidateList.length; i++){
          sum += votesReceived[candidateList[i]];
      }
      return sum;
  }

}
```

When I try to call function **voteForCandidate** I get this error from Remix :

*Gas estimation failed
Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending? 
VM Exception while processing transaction: revert*

When I try to force sending nothing happens.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a quick look at your code it looks like the only reason why `voteForCandidate` would `revert` would be if the candidate you're passing it isn't in your `candidateList`, so it fails the `validCandidate` test. Check the content of `candidateList` is what you expect, and check the parameter is being passed correctly into `voteForCandidate()`.